# How to pass query parameter to entity framework while programming against Base Entity?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In my project previously I was having individual repository for each entity but I am now refactoring it to a common repository while taking advantage of Base Entity.

**BaseEntity.cs :**

```
 public abstract class BaseEntity<T> : IEntity<T>
    {
        [NotMapped]
        public abstract T Id { get;  set; }
    }
```

**EFRepository.cs:**

```
 public class EFRepository<TEntity, TId> : IRepository<TEntity, TId> where 
              TEntity : BaseEntity<TId>, new()
    {
        private readonly IDbContext _context;
        private DbSet<TEntity> _entities;

        public EFRepository(IDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        private DbSet<TEntity> Entities
        {
            get { return _entities ?? (_entities = _context.Set<TEntity>()); }
        }

        public async Task<TEntity> GetByIdAsync(TId id)
        {
            return await Entities.FindAsync(id);
        }

        public void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            Entities.Add(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public async Task UpdateAsync(TEntity entity)
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        public void Delete(TId id)
        {
            var entity = new TEntity
            {
                Id = id
            };

            // Attach the entity to the context and call the delete method.
            Entities.Attach(entity);
            Delete(entity);
        }

        public void Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
            Entities.Remove(entity);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public IList<TEntity> Table
        {
            get { return Entities.ToList(); }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (_context != null)
                {
                    _context.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

The above implementation works perfect in most of the cases, but there's on scenario in which I have a customer entity and that customer entity contains field `SearchTerms` so in case if I have to perform filter base on the `SearchTerms` I am not able to achieve it with above approach. Also I don't want to add that field in Base Entity as it's just specific to Customer Entity.
Any help on how I can filter the result base on `SearchTerms`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate `CustomerRepository` class and implement your own filter logic as like below.

```
public class CustomerRepository : EFRepository<Customer, Guid>, ICustomerRepository
{
    public CustomerRepository(IDbContext context): base(context) {}

    public async Task<List<Customer>> GetCustomerBySearchTerms(string[] searchTerms)
    {
       //implement your logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was also planning to do the same but as I already have CustomerService so shall I create instance of `EFRepository` and use it or creating separate repository would be an ideal solution?

Comment: Repository is the place where you can interact with `DbContext`, so I suggest to create separate `CustomerRepositoy` class to solve this problem.

Comment: That's correct, Will follow that approach. But compiling your code is giving error as `There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'context' of 'EFRepository<Customer, Guid>.EFRepository(IDbContext)'`. Am I missing something?

Comment: you need to pass constructor value to your base class; updated the code snippet please take a look.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that. Thanks.